# Elif error occured while the python programming

Tags: python

```
# Get the input values.
b1 = input('Please enter the base.')
i1 = input('Please enter the index.')

# Define the funciton with parameter 'base' and 'index'.
def square(base, index):
    if base == 0:
        print('Can\'t calculate because base is equal to 0.')
    elif (not base == 0) and index == 0:
        print('The value is 0, because base is greater than 1, and index is equal to 0.')
    elif (not base == 0) and index == 1:
        print('The answer is equal to base, because index is equal to 1. Therefore, The answer is {ans}.'.format(ans=base))
    elif (not base == 0) and index == 2:
        print('{b} squared is {c}.'.format(b=base, c=(b ** 2))
    elif (not base == 0) and (index > 2 or index < 0):
        print('{b} to the power of {i} is equal to {c}'.format(b=base, i=index, c=base**index))

# Print the function.
print(square(b1, i1))
```

The error is this:

line 36, elif (not base == 0) and (index > 2 or index < 0):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I use python 3.5.1.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe use an `else`... Also, you don't need the `not base == 0`, you can assume that since your `if` wasn't run.

Comment: @HemanGandhi You can't just assume it; you *know* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on that line, but on the line above.  You did not close enough parentheses.  Try adding another close parenthesis to the end of the previous line.